# Jom error while trying to compile a project in QT

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I am trying to run my project and it manages to build but quickly terminates due to this compile error. I'm using 64 bit libraries for windows kits 10, visual studio 14 and directx.

```
    13:29:13: Running steps for project Phase64...
13:29:13: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
13:29:13: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_MSC_VER=1900 -D_WIN32 -D_WIN64 -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc2015 -IC:/Users/Phenom/Documents/QT/Phase64 -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10150.0/ucrt" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)/Include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)/Include" -IC:/boost/boost_1_61_0 -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)/Include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/atlmfc/include" -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore -I. ..\Phase64\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/atlmfc/include/atlbase.(3210): Parse error at "__identifier"
jom: C:\Users\me\Documents\QT\build-Phase64-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp] Error 1
    cl -c -FIstdafx.h -Yustdafx.h -Fpdebug\Phase64_pch.pch -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc /Fddebug\Phase64.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\Phase64 -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Include" -IC:\boost\boost_1_61_0 -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include" -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Phenom\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.1416.31.jom
main.cpp
    cl -c -FIstdafx.h -Yustdafx.h -Fpdebug\Phase64_pch.pch -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc /Fddebug\Phase64.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\Phase64 -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Include" -IC:\boost\boost_1_61_0 -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include" -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Phenom\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.1416.47.jom
mainwindow.cpp
jom: C:\me\Phenom\Documents\QT\build-Phase64-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
13:29:17: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Phase64 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2015 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
13:29:17: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: This can have many causes. What does the rest of the log look like? Qt Creator scrolls the error log window to about this level, effectively hiding all the useful information to the unaware user.

Comment: @rubenvb I've updated the post and added the whole log.

Comment: OK, not that helpful as I'd hoped. Can you uncheck the "use jom instead of nmake" option on the first tab in Options->Build&Run, and try again? Might be a jom issue.

Comment: I just tried that now and I received 2 build errors. Both errors state that the nmake file not found. `NMAKE:-1: error: U1077: 'C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin\moc.exe' : return code '0x1'
NMAKE:-1: error: U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'`

Comment: Ignore that. It's not a jom issue. It's a moc/atl/localized issue (see below).

Answer (score 1):

Your extended log shows that Qt's `moc` is choking on the ATL header:

```
C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_MSC_VER=1900 -D_WIN32 -D_WIN64 -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc2015 -IC:/Users/Phenom/Documents/QT/Phase64 -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10150.0/ucrt" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)/Include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)/Include" -IC:/boost/boost_1_61_0 -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)/Include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/atlmfc/include" -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015_64/include/QtCore -I. ..\Phase64\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/atlmfc/include/atlbase.(3210): Parse error at "__identifier"
```

This means any of the following:

1. `moc` can't handle the ATL smudge, in which case you'd need to ask Qt for a solution (e.g. by submitting a bug report with a !minimal! example code (e.g. a project including only three files: `main.cpp`, `some_qobject.h`/`.cpp`, where the last one is a complete reduction of your `..\Phase64\mainwindow.h`/`.cpp`) to reproduce this. (report it [here](http://bugreports.qt.io))
2. You are messing with macros/identifiers such as `__identifier` in your code, which are reserved by the implementation. Fix your code to not do this.
3. Qt's `moc` genuinely cannot handle the ATL headers. Change your code so that the `moc`ed file doesn't include the ATL headers. `moc` defines a `Q_MOC_RUN` macro, so you can wrap the ATL headers in `#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN`...`#endif` to let moc ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with `Qt 5.9.2`. To fix it at least temporary, include this line of code to the pro file and run clean, qmake and build the project:

```
DEFINES += _ATL_NATIVE_INITIALIZATION
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known regression in moc after Qt 5.8:  https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56634

The report claims a fix was merged into 5.9.2, but I'm still seeing problems.